# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error received asp.net web service

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making a getJSON request and recieving the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <. I am not sure what to look for, I send up the correct data, and I see xml in my response.

```
 $.getJSON('https://www.domain.com/MainService.asmx/LoginMobile?jsoncallback=?', parameter, function (data, textStatus) {
                showDialogMessage('Login error', textStatus);
            });
```

Comment: "and I see **xml** in my response." vs **getJSON** o_O xml != json

Comment: why is xml in my response. I just would like to get json?

Comment: `getJSON` accepts only json. It follows from its name and documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you are not using the webservice properly, or the webservice doesn't support JSONP. Look at the documentation for said webservice.